# Why does using < instead of <= gives time limit exceeded in the question "Find count of Rotations of an array"?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

I was practicing questions on modified binary search and I came across a question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rotation4723/1#

I wrote a code for it and tried few test cases on it and it worked as expected. This is the code which I wrote.

```
int findKRotation(int arr[], int n)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = n - 1;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (mid < end && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1])
            return mid + 1;
        if (mid > start && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] < arr[start])
            end = mid - 1;
        else
            start = mid;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the same on geekforgeeks judge and it gave me TLE but when I made just one modification by changing `arr[mid] < arr[start]` to `arr[mid] <= arr[start]` it worked perfectly fine.

Here is the final modified code which got accepted.

```
int findKRotation(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = n - 1;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (mid < end && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1])
            return mid + 1;
        if (mid > start && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] <= arr[start])
            end = mid - 1;
        else
            start = mid;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first code gave me TLE so that probably means it's not wrong but some test case is not getting passed probably. I tried to dry run it many times but no success. I guess I'm too dumb to understand the difference.

Comment: What does your own analysis of this code tell you? What loop invariants do you have in both versions?

Comment: Consider what happens when the array has 2 elements.

Comment: Debugging tip: What is the difference between `arr[mid] < arr[start]` and `arr[mid] <= arr[start]`? Hopefully, you realize it's the equality test. So change your `if-else` to `if (arr[mid] < arr[start]) end = mid - 1; else if (arr[mid] == arr[start]) start = mid; else start = mid;`. Set a breakpoint on the added line (the equality case) and try to concoct a test case that hits that line. Once you know how to hit that line, you can look into why you should change `end` instead of `start`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, assuming first 2 if clauses are not met - and `mid==start` - this is going to be the steady state.

You will fall into the else clause, set `start = mid` (which was already the case), and repeat the loop - with the exact same values.

This means, you will fall back into the same clause, and keep repeating your self forever.

Example `[1, 1]`:

```
start = 0
end = 1
mid = 0
(mid < end && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]) yields false
(mid > start && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]) yields false
arr[mid] < arr[start] yields false
```

And then you are "doomed" to repea the loop after changing nothing in the else clasue.